# Can't compile procedure that seems to be running

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got a very weird case. There's a proc that runs nightly. I know that it runs, 'cause I get an email from it every night.
This proc is part of a job chain, if it were to fail, the whole chain should fail and I should get an alert on my phone.
That being said, when I try to compile this particular piece of code, it errors out. I get an invalid column name RowID.

I'm wondering if the version in front of me is actually not the current version on the server or something? How else can this code run daily, but not compile ...

Here're the first few lines of the code. I should point out, I inherited this, and did not write this. Error occurs on second to last line. Table mentioned does not have a rowid column.

```
set nocount on
-- declare all variables
DECLARE @iNextRowId int,
 @iCurrentRowId int,
 @iLoopControl int,
 @PRODUCT VARCHAR(8),
 @MEDIACODE VARCHAR(8),
 @QTY INTEGER,
 @LISTNAME VARCHAR(50),
 @LISTNAME1 VARCHAR(50),
 @LISTNAME2 VARCHAR(50),
 @SLISTNAME VARCHAR(2)


-- Initialize variables
SELECT @iLoopControl = 1
SELECT @iNextRowId = MIN(RowId)
FROM   server..OrdTable ORD1
```

Comment: Where did you get the code? Is it from source control or the server?

Comment: What user does it run as?  That user may have file permissions that your login lacks.

Comment: There's definitely no other jobs running that might also send that email?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the server. Its not possible for us to tell you whats is currently live in your environment.

You can call:

```
exec sp_helptext 'procedure_name'
```

to see what is contained in the current proc in your live environment.

If the current live proc is the same, its possible that its a permissions issue, or that the chain doesnt work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I've inherited some pretty epic spagetti code here.
In an earlier proc that this job goes through, it adds a column to the table in order to allow it to loop, and then drops the column. I'm getting the error, 'cause I have to add the column first ...